# "Can't locate Parse/Pidl/IDL.pm" while installing Parse::Pidl

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm having an error trying to install Parse::Pidl module with cpan.
It seems that within the downloaded archive Parse-Pidl-0.02.tar.gz is missing the IDL.pm module
(I think it should be within Parse-Pidl-0.02.tar.gz, but not sure)

This was with perl v5.26.1 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
on Linux 5.14.21 (opensuse)

```
cpan Parse::Pidl
Loading internal null logger. Install Log::Log4perl for logging messages
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.62)
Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Fri, 25 Nov 2022 07:29:01 GMT
Running install for module 'Parse::Pidl'
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.96)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.074)
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/CT/CTRLSOFT/Parse-Pidl-0.02.tar.gz ok
CPAN: YAML loaded ok (v1.30)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta::Requirements loaded ok (v2.140)
CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
Configuring C/CT/CTRLSOFT/Parse-Pidl-0.02.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Parse::Pidl
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  CTRLSOFT/Parse-Pidl-0.02.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for C/CT/CTRLSOFT/Parse-Pidl-0.02.tar.gz
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20170922_26)
cp lib/Parse/Pidl/Samba4/Template.pm blib/lib/Parse/Pidl/Samba4/Template.pm
cp lib/Parse/Pidl/Samba4/SWIG.pm blib/lib/Parse/Pidl/Samba4/SWIG.pm
cp lib/Parse/Pidl/Ethereal/Conformance.pm blib/lib/Parse/Pidl/Ethereal/Conformance.pm
cp lib/Parse/Pidl/Samba4/COM/Stub.pm blib/lib/Parse/Pidl/Samba4/COM/Stub.pm
cp lib/Parse/Pidl.pm blib/lib/Parse/Pidl.pm
cp lib/Parse/Pidl/Compat.pm blib/lib/Parse/Pidl/Compat.pm
cp lib/Parse/Pidl/Ethereal/NDR.pm blib/lib/Parse/Pidl/Ethereal/NDR.pm
cp lib/Parse/Pidl/Samba4/TDR.pm blib/lib/Parse/Pidl/Samba4/TDR.pm
cp lib/Parse/Pidl/Typelist.pm blib/lib/Parse/Pidl/Typelist.pm
cp lib/Parse/Pidl/Samba4/COM/Proxy.pm blib/lib/Parse/Pidl/Samba4/COM/Proxy.pm
cp lib/Parse/Pidl/Samba4/NDR/Parser.pm blib/lib/Parse/Pidl/Samba4/NDR/Parser.pm
cp lib/Parse/Pidl/Samba4/COM/Header.pm blib/lib/Parse/Pidl/Samba4/COM/Header.pm
cp lib/Parse/Pidl/ODL.pm blib/lib/Parse/Pidl/ODL.pm
cp lib/Parse/Pidl/Samba4/NDR/Client.pm blib/lib/Parse/Pidl/Samba4/NDR/Client.pm
cp lib/Parse/Pidl/Samba4/Header.pm blib/lib/Parse/Pidl/Samba4/Header.pm
cp lib/Parse/Pidl/Samba4/EJS.pm blib/lib/Parse/Pidl/Samba4/EJS.pm
cp lib/Parse/Pidl/NDR.pm blib/lib/Parse/Pidl/NDR.pm
cp lib/Parse/Pidl/Dump.pm blib/lib/Parse/Pidl/Dump.pm
cp lib/Parse/Pidl/Util.pm blib/lib/Parse/Pidl/Util.pm
cp lib/Parse/Pidl/Samba4/NDR/Server.pm blib/lib/Parse/Pidl/Samba4/NDR/Server.pm
cp pidl blib/script/pidl
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::MY -e 'MY->fixin(shift)' -- blib/script/pidl
Manifying 1 pod document
Manifying 4 pod documents
  CTRLSOFT/Parse-Pidl-0.02.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" tests/*.pl
tests/ndr_align.pl ... Can't locate Parse/Pidl/IDL.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Parse::Pidl::IDL module) (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/tests /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/tests/../lib /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/blib/arch /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26.1 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26.1 /usr/lib/perl5/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.26.1 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl .) at /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/tests/Util.pm line 14.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/tests/Util.pm line 14.
Compilation failed in require at tests/ndr_align.pl line 10.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at tests/ndr_align.pl line 10.
# Looks like your test exited with 2 before it could output anything.
tests/ndr_align.pl ... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 40/40 subtests 
tests/ndr_alloc.pl ... Can't locate Parse/Pidl/IDL.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Parse::Pidl::IDL module) (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/tests /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/tests/../lib /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/blib/arch /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26.1 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26.1 /usr/lib/perl5/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.26.1 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl .) at /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/tests/Util.pm line 14.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/tests/Util.pm line 14.
Compilation failed in require at tests/ndr_alloc.pl line 10.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at tests/ndr_alloc.pl line 10.
# Looks like your test exited with 2 before it could output anything.
tests/ndr_alloc.pl ... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 40/40 subtests 
tests/ndr_array.pl ... Can't locate Parse/Pidl/IDL.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Parse::Pidl::IDL module) (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/tests /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/tests/../lib /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/blib/arch /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26.1 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26.1 /usr/lib/perl5/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.26.1 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl .) at /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/tests/Util.pm line 14.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/tests/Util.pm line 14.
Compilation failed in require at tests/ndr_array.pl line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at tests/ndr_array.pl line 11.
# Looks like your test exited with 2 before it could output anything.
tests/ndr_array.pl ... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 8/8 subtests 
tests/ndr_refptr.pl .. Can't locate Parse/Pidl/IDL.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Parse::Pidl::IDL module) (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/tests /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/tests/../lib /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/blib/arch /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26.1 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26.1 /usr/lib/perl5/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.26.1 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl .) at /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/tests/Util.pm line 14.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/tests/Util.pm line 14.
Compilation failed in require at tests/ndr_refptr.pl line 12.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at tests/ndr_refptr.pl line 12.
# Looks like your test exited with 2 before it could output anything.
tests/ndr_refptr.pl .. Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 168/168 subtests 
tests/ndr_simple.pl .. Can't locate Parse/Pidl/IDL.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Parse::Pidl::IDL module) (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/tests /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/tests/../lib /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/blib/arch /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26.1 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26.1 /usr/lib/perl5/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.26.1 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl .) at /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/tests/Util.pm line 14.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/tests/Util.pm line 14.
Compilation failed in require at tests/ndr_simple.pl line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at tests/ndr_simple.pl line 11.
# Looks like your test exited with 2 before it could output anything.
tests/ndr_simple.pl .. Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 8/8 subtests 
tests/ndr_string.pl .. Can't locate Parse/Pidl/IDL.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Parse::Pidl::IDL module) (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/tests /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/tests/../lib /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/blib/arch /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26.1 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26.1 /usr/lib/perl5/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.26.1 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl .) at /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/tests/Util.pm line 14.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/tests/Util.pm line 14.
Compilation failed in require at tests/ndr_string.pl line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at tests/ndr_string.pl line 11.
# Looks like your test exited with 2 before it could output anything.
tests/ndr_string.pl .. Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 16/16 subtests 
tests/parse_idl.pl ... Can't locate Parse/Pidl/IDL.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Parse::Pidl::IDL module) (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/tests/../lib /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/Parse-Pidl-0.02-1/blib/arch /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26.1 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26.1 /usr/lib/perl5/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.26.1 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl .) at tests/parse_idl.pl line 10.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at tests/parse_idl.pl line 10.
# Looks like your test exited with 2 before it could output anything.
tests/parse_idl.pl ... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 51/51 subtests 

Test Summary Report
-------------------
tests/ndr_align.pl (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 40 tests but ran 0.
tests/ndr_alloc.pl (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 40 tests but ran 0.
tests/ndr_array.pl (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 8 tests but ran 0.
tests/ndr_refptr.pl (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 168 tests but ran 0.
tests/ndr_simple.pl (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 8 tests but ran 0.
tests/ndr_string.pl (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 16 tests but ran 0.
tests/parse_idl.pl (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 51 tests but ran 0.
Files=7, Tests=0,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr  0.00 sys +  0.19 cusr  0.04 csys =  0.25 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 7/7 test programs. 0/0 subtests failed.
make: *** [Makefile:880: test_dynamic] Error 2
  CTRLSOFT/Parse-Pidl-0.02.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports CTRLSOFT/Parse-Pidl-0.02.tar.gz
```

Any ideas on how to complete the install ?

Comment: The file `Parse::Pidl::IDL` should be generated by yapp when running `perl Makefile.PL`, see https://metacpan.org/release/CTRLSOFT/Parse-Pidl-0.02/source/Makefile.PL#L12

Comment: So maybe `yapp` isn't installed? It's annoying that this doesn't result in an error message if that's the case.

Comment: After installing yapp, and checked it on cmdline, i retried manually the build: downloaded the archive, uncompressed, perl Makefile.PL ; make ; make test. Same error. Despite @Håkon tips nor IDL nor IDL.pm was produced into build directory tree, and tests failed in same manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The installation process is supposed to [create](https://metacpan.org/release/CTRLSOFT/Parse-Pidl-0.02/source/Makefile.PL#L12) `lib/Parse/Pidl/IDL.pm`, but it doesn't.<sup>[1]</sup>

But you can work around this.

```bash
cpan Parse::Yapp
wget https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/C/CT/CTRLSOFT/Parse-Pidl-0.02.tar.gz
tar xzf Parse-Pidl-0.02.tar.gz
cd Parse-Pidl-0.02
perl Makefile.PL
yapp -s -m 'Parse::Pidl::IDL' -o lib/Parse/Pidl/IDL.pm idl.yp
make test
make install
```

This is just what `cpan` does, with two additions: Installing Parse::Yapp to provide `yapp`, and running `yapp` manually.

---

1. I don't have time to look into why.